# Is my code to retrieve a content object and property from a JCR repository valid?

Tags: java, jcr, magnolia

I am finishing up a book for O'Reilly (http://flyingsquirrelbook.com/).

In this book, I compare several examples of code to (1) retrieve a content object from a repository, and (2) retrieve a single property/attribute from that object.  I do this to demonstrate the APIs of different CMS are different, yet somewhat similar in logic.  I have examples from C# (Episerver), PHP (Concrete5), Python (Plone), and Magnolia (Java, using JCR).

I have validated the first three, but I have no experience with Java or JCR. I need someone to look at this code and tell me if this is a reasonably accepted way to do what I state above:

```
Session session = MgnlContext.getJCRSession("myWorkspace");
Node myPage = session.getNodeByIdentifier("123");
String title = myPage.getProperty("PageTitle").getValue().getString()
```

Is that egregiously wrong, for any reason?

Comment: Does it *work?* Do you have any reason to believe it is egregiously wrong? Do you really think StackOverflow is a reasonable way to conduct research for a book?

Comment: I don't know, I'm not a Java developer. While yes, I am researching a book, this is still -- at its core -- a technical question about the accuracy of code.  I think that's perfectly appropriate. It's not like I'm asking for someone's opinion or taking a survey. In a practical sense, would it be any different if I was just trying to get this code to execute somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While you wouldn't get compiler complaining about the code, there's few things you can do to improve on example.
`getNodeByIdentifier()` method takes node if in UUID format, so you should show same instead of using simple Int as Id.
Similarly property names typically start with lowercase.
And last call to `getValue()` is unnecessary. You can call `getString()` directly on property object.

HTH,
Jan

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thank you.

Comment: Or use `PropertyUtil.getString(myPage, "PageTitle")` (there is also a `getString` method with a third argument for a default value). The page title property for a Magnolia page is actually just `title` by the way. And the Magnolia workspace for pages is called `website`.

Answer (score 1):

The [Apache Jackrabbit "first hops" page](http://jackrabbit.apache.org/jcr/first-hops.html) has some examples you might find helpful.

Specifically, the SecondHop class shows how to create, retrieve, and delete content. Here's a snippet showing retrieval:

```
Node node = root.getNode("hello/world"); 
System.out.println(node.getPath()); 
System.out.println(node.getProperty("message").getString());
```

That example gets the node using getNode(), but you can also get it by identifier as you've done:

```
Node node = session.getNodeByIdentifier(id);
```

Aside from the getString() that Jan mentioned, your third line is missing a semicolon.